# Deleting file by specifying full path - why does this work?

Tags: windows-7, unc

Attempting to delete a folder in Explorer failed with `error 0x80070091: the directory is not empty`. `del` from admin command prompt gave a 'permission denied' error. Permissions and ownership in order.

`del \\?\c:\path\to\folder` succeeded. Why does this work when `del c:\path\to\folder` does not?

**EDIT:** Path length was 29 characters, as in:
`C:\users\A-AAAAAA\desktop\BBB` (actual format of path with personal info redacted—char counts match. BBB is folder in question).

Comment: What kind of filesystem is this, and which OS are you using?

Comment: @SadBunny NTFS, Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason the "full path" works, is because Windows might not be viewing it as a folder when accessed with a fully qualified path.

The `del` command is used for deleting files.

The `rd` command (remove directory) is used for deleting folders.

If you want to delete a folder run:

`rd C:\path\to\folder`

If you want to delete a folder tree (including files and subfolders) run:

`rd /s C:\path\to\folder`

Also, running the command `del C:\path\to\folder` in command prompt will actually not delete a folder, but rather delete the contents of that folder, so think of it more like an alias for `del C:\path\to\folder\*`.

Comment: Good point. I should have specified that the prompt returned by `del` asks to confirm deletion of `..\BBB\*`. Unfortunately I can't recreate this folder to test `rd`.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably a very long pathname or filename? I never heard of this before, but I googled a bit and apparently your syntax can be used to delete those.

http://ss64.com/nt/del.html:

```
Undeletable Files

Files are sometimes created with the very long filenames or reserved names:
CON, AUX, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, PRN, NUL 
To delete these use the syntax: DEL \\.\C:\somedir\LPT1
Alternatively SUBST a drive letter to the folder containing the file.
```

Comment: it wasn't over the 260-character limit that Windows generally imposes. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx